# react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function show in the console of localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs

after I created react.js project when I put any type of code it doesn't show in the localhost
so when i inspect and open the console tap it show me this error:
**`Uncaught TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function`**

```
at Module../src/index.js (index.js:7:1)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at startup:7:1
at startup:7:1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The above used method is now deprecated for newer import methods in the React 18.

You can use this to solve the problem.

```
import {StrictMode} from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react- 
dom/client';

import App from './App'
```

// this is the ID of the div in your index.html file

```
const rootElement = 
document.getElementById('root');
const root = 
createRoot(rootElement);
```

// ️ if you use TypeScript, add non-null (!) assertion operator
//

```
const root = createRoot(rootElement!);
```

Then

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

create root with const

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

and instead of ReactDOM.render use

root.render

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).