# Error with ReactDom while creating an app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on this project currently and this is my final assignment of the semester. I created this project and finished coding down but when I load the `localhost`, the page stays blank though the `console` in `vsc` shows no error. I checked the `console` and it shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a functionUncaught TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function

Here is the code that's in my vsc:

`import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

`
[The console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiJi5.png)

Comment: What version of react did you install? Since version 18 `render` has been removed

Comment: I think what you are trying is deprecated. \
Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945583/react-dom-client-webpack-imported-module-1-render-is-not-a-function-show-in-t).

Answer (score 0):

change your import in the 'index.js'

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

to

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

delete 'client'