# How do I see my project on localhost using VS/React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a novice independent programmer, still I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a blank screen on the localhost server, this is the error I'm getting...

"Uncaught TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function
js index.js:5
factory react refresh:6
Webpack 3
"

I was practicing on react, expecting to see my files of html, js and css on the web project, I only get a blank website instead

Comment: check out this questions: [your related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945583/react-dom-client-webpack-imported-module-1-render-is-not-a-function-show-in-t)